# shortcut to files on network share whose name keep changing constantly

Tags: windows-7

There is a network share used as repository in my company and it is quite difficult to navigate through it and find certain files. Some of these files get a new name every day , usually the date changes, which makes it impossible to create shortcuts to them. Usually these are excel or word files. Is there a way I can create a shortcut to that file even though the date has changed on the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely have to use a shortcut (lnk file) for this the only workaround that comes to mind is pointing the shortcut to an environment variable and changing that programatically (wildcards are not supported in lnk files afaik).

However I assume that in most cases what you want is not really a shortcut in its technical definition but rather a way to open the file you want with a double click. In this case it would be a lot easier to just use a simple script that figures out what the name of the file currently is (by whatever rules you use manually) and launch it.

Should be doable in vbscript or powershell (maybe even batch) just fine as long as there is some logical way to determine which file is the right one (e.g. always the current date, always the file where the date is newest, the only file with extension xlsx, ...)

Comment: it doesn't have to be necessarily a standard Windows shortcut,

Comment: In that case really just use a vbscript or powershell file. It can be written to search for your document (or even multiple documents) and open them all. You just have to find a method to identify which ones you want but that is basically the same "algorithm" you use when you do it manually